# How to evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{{4e^{2x}-2e^x+1}}{2e^{2x}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm finding this question challenging, and there are several like it in my revision paper.

How do you rearrange the expression, and at what stage should I differentiate?
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{{4e^{2x}-2e^x+1}}{2e^{2x}}$$

---

The answer in the back of the book: $e^{-2x}(e^x-1)$

*Thank you for your time~!*

Comment: Take $ e^{x}=u$ and apply Chain Rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start by writing
$$\frac{4e^{2x}-2e^x+1}{2e^{2x}}=2-e^{-x}+\frac{e^{-2x}}2.$$

Comment: After looking at this for a few minutes I think I understand how to get to the answer, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d}{dx}(2-\frac{1}{e^x}+\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{e^{2x}})$ = 0+$\frac{d}{dx}(-e^{-x})$+$\frac{1}{2}*\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-2x})$=$e^{-x}-e^{-2x}=e^{-2x}(e^x-1)$

Comment: this helped me confirm the last step, thankyou!

Comment: your welcome my pleasure.

Comment: are you taking an exam?

Comment: I have one tomorrow ^_^

Comment: are you taking A -levels?

Comment: Not sure what that is, but i'm in an advanced diploma of engineering technology. Is there a private message service on here somehwere?